# android - replace layout programmatically and using ViewStub

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, viewstub

I am trying to implement a Newsfeed-type layout with multiple feed items.
The newsfeed item would have a certain layout when collapsed, and this layout would be replaced by an 'exploded' version, when the item is clicked.

I accomplished this by using a ListView of custom items. The custom item XML layout file has a ViewStub which is what I used to change the layout back and forth.
Now, though, I wanted to 'migrate' the layout over to RecyclerView, and to also follow a ViewHolder design pattern.
The latter is what I have tried first, and I'm running into all sorts of problems.

My approach has been as follows:

1. Get reference to collapsed layout (events_list_item_content) and expanded layout (events_list_item_selected_content);
2. Get reference to a simple layout resource file to be set as the ViewStub layout (view_stub_layout).
3. Get ViewStub reference, set its layout (view_stub_layout) inflate, and add the collapsed layout view to this layout (when first creating the feed, all of its items are going to be collapsed).
4. (After initialisation, when an item is clicked) Remove previous view (layout) from the ViewStubLayout, add the other type of layout.

Here is my custom adapter class:

```
public class FeedRecyclerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public class ViewHolder {
    View inflatedViewStub1;  
    ViewStub viewStub;
    LinearLayout  viewStubLayout;
    LinearLayout listItemContent, listItemContentSelected;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list_item_content_new_container, parent, false);
        View view = null;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list_item_content, null);
        viewHolder.listItemContent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.events_list_item_content);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list_item_selected_content, null);
        viewHolder.listItemContentSelected = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.events_list_item_content_selected);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_stub_layout, null);
        viewHolder.viewStubLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.view_stub_layout);

        viewHolder.viewStub = (ViewStub) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_feed);           

 (viewHolder.viewStubLayout).addView(viewHolder.listItemContent);
        viewHolder.viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.view_stub_layout);
        viewHolder.inflatedViewStub1 = viewHolder.viewStub.inflate();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (item.getExploded()) {
        viewHolder.viewStubLayout.removeAllViews();
        viewHolder.viewStubLayout.addView(viewHolder.listItemContentSelected);
    } else {
        viewHolder.viewStubLayout.removeAllViews();
        viewHolder.viewStubLayout.addView(viewHolder.listItemContent);
    }
  return convertView;
  }
```

However, when testing, the page where the Newsfeed is supposed to appear is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
stub.setLayoutResource(layoutId);
stub.inflate(); // inflate 1st layout

ll.removeAllViews(); // remove previous view, add 2nd layout
ll.addView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(secondLayoutId, ll, false));
```

[Android ViewStub change layouts programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441226/android-viewstub-change-layouts-programatically)

Comment: I've seen that post already...  in this answer, when is the layout that I want to load ever set as the ViewStub's layout resource?
Is LinearLayout ll ever set as the ViewStub's layout resource? What are layoutId and secondLayoutId?