# Inflate ViewStub with a native widget

Tags: android, android-layout, viewstub

Is it possible to inflate a ViewStub with a native android widget?

For example:

```
<LinearLayout...>
 <TextView...>
 <TextView...>
 <ViewStub...>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to replace/inflate the ViewStub with a Switch or a Checkbox. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you read here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442268/2910520, what you need is the same thing

Comment: Yes I did. It's not quite the same thing as the layout I'm trying to inflate is for a native android widget. I don't have an explicit layout for it.

Comment: You should create a new layout representing the thing you want to inflate. Currently there is no way to inflate a View object in a StubView

Answer (score 0):

To set the layout to inflate into the `ViewStub` either:

Set the layout via XML:

```
<ViewStub 
   android:id="@+id/stub"
   android:inflatedId="@+id/myLayout"
   android:layout="@layout/myLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or, set the layout at runtime:

```
viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.myLayout);
```

Then, you can inflate the `ViewStub`.

```
View inflatedView = viewStub.inflate();
```

You could call this `inflate()` method from where you want, such as a `Switch` or `Checkbox` being clicked (as you asked).

Comment: So what layout resource should it be set to if I want to inflate a native android switch widget?

Comment: You create a layout file that contains a Switch widget. Then inflate that layout resource.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to replace the `StubView` with a `View` object. You must create a layout representing the view you want to replace. So for example, if you want to switch it with a single `CheckBox`, you need to create a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
    android:text="Click me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then calling

```
viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_checkbox);
viewStub.inflate();
```

If you need a reference to the inflated view you can use this instead

```
CheckBox checkInflated = (CheckBox)viewStub.inflate();
```